# Split but exclude comma out of line (CSV to JSON)

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script that converts CSV files to JSON to manipulate the JSON data, then convert that new JSON data back to CSV. I cannot use any external libraries because I am developing within a platform that does not allow this unfortunately.

I am somewhat able to parse a CSV to JSON, and I am doing this by splitting the file up using `split(",")`.

The issue is, that there are commas in the description header of these CSV files which causes the file to split improperly if there is more than one comma in the description header.

For ex:

I have a description with text of: `Pipette Wide Orifice Graduated, PP 10mL`

I need to be able to write logic to ignore that comma in the description, so that the integrity of the description does not actually change. What currently happens is that the script will split the description at the first comma so that the description becomes `Pipette Wide Orifice Graduated` and then the next header will contain `PP 10mL` which needs to stay part of the description.

This is my current function:

```
function csvJson(fileContents) {
                var lines = fileContents.split("\n");
                var result = [];
                var headers = lines[0].split(",");

                for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    var obj = {};

                    var currentLine = lines[i].split(",");

                    for(var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                        obj[headers[j]] = currentLine[j];
                    }

                    result.push(obj);
                }

                return JSON.stringify(result);
            }
```

To reiterate, I am basically trying to ensure that if there is already a comma somewhere within the CSV file contents, to not split the lines there and to only split at the end of each actual line through commas created via the logic itself. Hopefully that makes sense!

Please let me know if I can elaborate or provide additional info.

Thanks!

Ex of fileContents:

```
    [{"CATALOG NUMBER":"102774-0010","DESCRIPTION":"\"Pipette Wide Orifice Graduated","NEW":" PP 10mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"16.1375118","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"9.68250708","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/102774-0010.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"103164","DESCRIPTION":"\"Rack Rodac Plate","NEW":" Acrylic/PC 60-65mm\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"70.4658636","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"42.27951816","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/103164.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"103164-01","DESCRIPTION":"\"Rack Rodac Plate","NEW":" Acrylic/PC 100mm\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"69.7817394","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"41.86904364","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/103164-01.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"103205","DESCRIPTION":"\"Rack Thermometer 25 Place","NEW":" HDPE \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"49.7795904","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"24.8897952","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/103205.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"103215-0000","DESCRIPTION":"\"Rack Hydrometer Tall 18 Place","NEW":" PP \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"91.988802","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"45.994401","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/103215-0000.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"103215-0001","DESCRIPTION":"\"Rack Hydrometer Short 18 Place","NEW":" PP \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"91.988802","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"45.994401","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/103215-0001.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105414","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Spigot","NEW":" LDPE 1gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"6","DEALER DISCOUNT":"504.4068504","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"302.6441102","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"6","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105414.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105424","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Spigot","NEW":" LDPE 2gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"6","DEALER DISCOUNT":"679.5862812","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"407.7517687","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"6","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105424.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105444","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Spigot","NEW":" LDPE 6.5gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"167.5796862","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"100.5478117","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105444.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105665","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy Square w Tubing/Clamp","NEW":" HDPE 5gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"67.3472136","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"33.6736068","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105665.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105674-0001","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Tubing and Clamp","NEW":" LDPE 1gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"6","DEALER DISCOUNT":"489.0864708","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.4","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"293.4518825","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"6","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105674-0001.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105674-0002","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Tubing and Clamp","NEW":" LDPE 2gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"6","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105674-0002.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105674-0006","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy w Tubing and Clamp","NEW":" LDPE 6.5gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105674-0006.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"105775","DESCRIPTION":"\"Carboy Square w Outlet","NEW":" HDPE 5gal\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"61.5917718","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"30.7958859","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/105775.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106105-01","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Needle Spray","NEW":" LDPE 1oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"12","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"48","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106105-01.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106105-02","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Needle Spray","NEW":" LDPE 2oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"12","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"48","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106105-02.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106105-04","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Needle Spray","NEW":" LDPE 4oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"12","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"48","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106105-04.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106105-08","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Needle Spray","NEW":" LDPE 8oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"12","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"36","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106105-08.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106105-16","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Needle Spray","NEW":" LDPE 16oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"TRUE","CONV FACTOR":"DISC","2020 LIST PRICE":"","DEALER DISCOUNT":"0.02","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.01","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"12","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"24","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106105-16.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106155-04","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Large Tubing","NEW":" LDPE 4oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"48","DEALER DISCOUNT":"171.3776256","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"85.6888128","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"48","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106155-04.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106155-08","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Large Tubing","NEW":" LDPE 8oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"36","DEALER DISCOUNT":"153.3082032","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"76.6541016","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"PK","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"6","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"CS","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"36","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106155-08.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106155-16","DESCRIPTION":"\"Washbottle Large Tubing","NEW":" LDPE 16oz\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"CS","2020 LIST PRICE":"24","DEALER DISCOUNT":"124.4117664","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"62.2058832","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"24","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106155-16.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106245","DESCRIPTION":"\"Work Station Storage Bin Lrg","NEW":" Acrylic \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"146.2589118","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"73.1294559","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106245.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106255","DESCRIPTION":"\"Work Station Storage Bin Sml","NEW":" Acrylic \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"110.6213868","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"55.3106934","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106255.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106265","DESCRIPTION":"\"Work Station Storage Bin Lrg","NEW":" Acrylic \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"151.9172598","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"75.9586299","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106265.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106275","DESCRIPTION":"\"Work Station Storage Bin Sml","NEW":" Acrylic \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"139.3075812","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"69.6537906","SHIP Sales UOM":"N","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106275.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106505","DESCRIPTION":"\"Dipper Large","NEW":" HDPE 32oz 3Ft\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"60.8420208","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"30.4210104","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106505.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106515","DESCRIPTION":"\"Dipper Large","NEW":" HDPE 32oz 6Ft\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"74.3393034","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"37.1696517","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106515.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"106525","DESCRIPTION":"\"Dipper Large","NEW":" HDPE 32oz 12Ft\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"124.805874","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"62.402937","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"CS","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/106525.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0001","DESCRIPTION":"\"Handle","NEW":" HDPE 1.5'\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"38.4559788","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"19.2279894","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0001.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0002","DESCRIPTION":"\"Handle","NEW":" HDPE 3'\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"46.854414","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"23.427207","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0002.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0003","DESCRIPTION":"\"Handle","NEW":" HDPE 6'\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"59.2310634","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"29.6155317","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0003.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0004","DESCRIPTION":"\"Beaker Double Spouted w Grad","NEW":" HDPE 250mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"33.6821442","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"16.8410721","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0004.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0005","DESCRIPTION":"\"Beaker Double Spouted w Grad","NEW":" HDPE 500mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"34.7871918","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"17.3935959","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0005.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0006","DESCRIPTION":"\"Beaker Double Spouted wGrad","NEW":" HDPE 1000mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"41.6827488","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"20.8413744","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0006.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0007","DESCRIPTION":"\"Stir Blade","NEW":" HDPE \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"25.2395124","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"12.6197562","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0007.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0008","DESCRIPTION":"\"Stir Blade Perforated","NEW":" HDPE \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"37.704555","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"18.8522775","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0008.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0009","DESCRIPTION":"\"Sampler w Grad Bottle","NEW":" HDPE/PP 100mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"67.0106544","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"33.5053272","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0009.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-0010","DESCRIPTION":"\"Sampler w Grad Bottle","NEW":" HDPE/PP 500mL\"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"97.863849","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"48.9319245","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-0010.jpg"},{"CATALOG NUMBER":"107035-1000","DESCRIPTION":"\"Dipper Sampling Kit","NEW":" HDPE \"","Discontinued":"","PRICE UOM":"","CONV FACTOR":"EA","2020 LIST PRICE":"1","DEALER DISCOUNT":"224.2492236","2020 DEALER PRICE":"0.5","CA Prop 65 Compliant":"112.1246118","SHIP Sales UOM":"Y","SHIP Units Per Pack":"EA","SHIP Alt Sales UOM":"1","SHIP Alt Units Per Pack":"","HIGH RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK":"","WEB LOW RESOLUTION PHOTO LINK\r":"https://www.dynalon.com/PublicStore/images/Assets/HR/107035-1000.jpg"}]
```

Comment: Could you provide a text snippet of the fileContents that gets passed to the function?

Comment: Added fileContents example! Thanks!

Thanks for sharing that thread as well. I am checking it out now!

Comment: You do realize there's libraries that handle this, and that it's somewhat more complex than one might think at first blush, right?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to mention I am developing within an ERP system called NetSuite which doesn't allow for 3rd party libraries :/ that's been something making this process difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can use this node package which handles that. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson